# How can I pass row data from DataTable as a function parameter with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, onclick, parameter-passing

The objective is to get the row data when clicking on the button of each row to execute another function. I tried to use Onclick with no success.

Below is my JavaScript

```
    function populateDataTable(data) {

    
    console.log("populating data table...");

    // clear the table before populating it with more data
    $("#tabela1").DataTable().clear();
    var length = Object.keys(data).length;
    console.log("Object length is " + length)
    for(let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    var dataTable = data[i]; // data is json parsed

    var actStatus = '<td class="align-middle situation" style="display: table-cell;" tabindex="0"><span class="badge badge-primary">'+dataTable.status+'</span></td>'
    var viewBtn = '<td class="align-middle moreOptions" style="display: table-cell;"><span tooltip="details" title=""><a class="fa fa-eye grey-text" data-placement="top" data-toggle="modal" href="#" onClick="actvDetails('+this.dataTable+')" data-backdrop="false"></a></span></td></tr>' 

    $('#tabela1').dataTable().fnAddData( [
            dataTable.id, 
            dataTable.number, 
            dataTable.limit,
            actStatus,
            dataTable.last_updated,
            viewBtn,
    ]);
    }
}

function actvDetails(dataTable) {
    console.log(dataTable);
    // process row data here
}
```

Here is my the row details

```
    {
    "id": 25,
    "number": "222222222",
    "sid": "4514585554578112",
    "code": "2545",
    "limit": "capped",
    "addon": "No Addon",
    "type": "admin",
    "comments": "Testing ",
    "requestor_id": "1255",
    "occ": "null",
    "status": "processing",
    "last_updated": "2023-02-12"
}
```

Comment: Add html if you can.
so Maybe: `actvDetails('+this.dataTable+')` change to `actvDetails('+dataTable+')`. ==> (remove `this`)

Comment: I'd add to @ramin comment that also the comment in your code `var dataTable = data[i]; // data is json parsed` says that variable dataTable is parsed json but later in the code you try to use it as a string `onClick="actvDetails('+dataTable+')"` It won't work because objects are converted to strings like `[object Object]`. You have to stringify the value before using it as string `onClick="actvDetails('+JSON.stringify(dataTable)+')"`.

Comment: @ramin I couldn't add the html table due to limitation on the editor. I tried actvDetails('+dataTable+') but no success.

Comment: I tried `onClick="actvDetails('+JSON.stringify(dataTable)+')"` but when executing the function `function actvDetails(dataTable) {console.log(dataTable);}` I get the error "unexpeted end of input" at `actvDetails({`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out a solution.

This converted the passed variable into a one line string separated by commas

```
var viewBtn = '<td class="align-middle moreOptions" style="display: table-cell;"><span tooltip="details" title=""><a class="fa fa-eye grey-text" data-placement="top" data-toggle="modal" href="#" onClick="actvDetails(\''+dataTable.id+', '+dataTable.number+', '+dataTable.limit+', '+dataTable.status+', '+dataTable.last_updated+', \')" data-backdrop="false"></a></span></td></tr>'
```

Then in JavaScript I used split

```
function actvDetails(passedData) {
  console.log(typeof passedData);

  console.log(passedData);
  var rowDetailsArray = passedData.split(", ") ;
  console.log(rowDetailsArray);
}
```